# Propane fireplace lites then goes out after ten min

Tags: heating

My fire place is LP gas and the pilot will lite and the flames/main burner comes on nice but only runs for about ten mins, then main burner and pilot go out...Not supposed to do this...Thermocoupler was just replaced a yr ago and is showing 400mv when tested...any ideas...?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you give us a make and model of the fireplace, and some more details (e.g. what exactly happens when the fire goes out)? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is the unit controlled by a thermostat, switch, or you just manually open a gas valve to light?